# Compactness in $L^p$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I am studying this article:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4883.pdf

There is a little part that I do not understand, in the proof of theorem 5, page 4.

Let $P$ be the projection map of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ onto the linear span of the characteristic functions of the cubes $Q_i$

It says that the function $P$ defined before, is bounded and is actually s.t. $||P||=1$

Now how can I see this?

I think $P:L^p(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow T$ where $T\subset L^p(\mathbb{R})$ $T=\{\lambda_1\chi_{Q_1}+\lambda_2\chi_{Q_2}+..+\lambda_N\chi_{Q_N}: \lambda_i\in R\} $ and $\chi_i$ are the characteristic functions.
But I don't really understand what norm they are considering for $P$,
 is it just the $L^p$ norm?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It seem like the norm they are using is $\| P \| = \sup_{\| f \| = 1 } \| Pf \|  $ (This is the usual norm for bounded linear operators).

Comment: ah ok tank you very much, then it actually is 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For boundedness, we use the fact that the cubes are not overlapping to get 
$$ \lVert Pf\rVert_p^p=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac 1{\left|C_i\right|^p} \left|\int_{C_i}f\right|^p \left|C_i\right|.$$
Then we use Jensen's inequality for the probability measure $\mathbf 1_{C_i}\mathrm dz/\left|C_i\right|$ to get the wanted result.